# What sort of data is this?

Tags: list, dictionary, parsing, types

I have this dataset which I need to parse. I'm not sure if it is a common format. It's not one I recognise, but that doesn't rule out a lot. If anyone can identify it, and perhaps point me to a python library that will help to parse it, that would be great!

Here's a sample:

```
{"demand":[["2021-07-28T07:20+09:30",24.4],["2021-07-28T07:25+09:30",24.8],["2021-07-28T07:30+09:30",25.0],...,["2021-07-28T19:20+09:30",26.1]]}
```

Comment: A json array of date/times? json, certainly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sample you shared, it looks like json for me.

You can load json in Python like this,

```
import json
  
# Opening JSON file
f = open('data.json', 'r')
  
# returns JSON object as 
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)
  
# Iterating through the json
# list
for i in data["demand"]:
    print(i)
  
# Closing file
f.close()
```